# How do I get a random row in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to retrieve a random row with CakePHP 3.0 RC-1, I've looked into [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-find-methods).

Using what I had from CakePHP 2.X and putting that as a starting point for getting a random row in CakePHP 3.0 RC-1. However, this is apparently not doing it for Miss Cake:

```
$result = $this->Game->find('all')
            ->order('rand()')
            ->limit(1);
```

The result yields nothing. There is data in the database, and I am able to retrieve single records. (I.e $this->Game->get(20) works like it should).

Comment: Works fine for me... how exactly are you testing for a result (just debugging `$result` won't execute the query)? ps, also try with a recent dev snapshot.

Comment: just var_dump the entire $game entity in View or in the Controller for that matter. This is the most recent dev snapshot.

Comment: There you have it, what you are doing is dumping a query, not a result. You'll have to actually fetch something first, for example by using `first()` (you can ditch the `limit()` then). See **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#the-query-object**

Comment: Then why do I see the result if I var_dump a resultset via ->GET but not through the code stated above?

Comment: Because `Table::get()` invokes `Query::firstOrFail()` internally (which again invokes `Query::first()`). I'd suggest to check the source (a proper IDE which let's you click through the method calls will help).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use "first" for getting the first result:

```
$result = $this->Game->find('all')
        ->order('rand()')
        ->first();
```

Alternatively, you can make it work like `get()` in that it will return an exception if no results are found:

```
$result = $this->Game->find('all')
        ->order('rand()')
        ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: This works, but how efficient is it since you're not limiting? (Find all sounds like you're getting a large resultset and then getting the first from that)

Comment: Using `RAND()` is always horrible, as it needs to get all results, order them randomly and then slice the results. Regarding your question, `firstOrFail` will apply a `LIMIT 1` for you. That does not mean that `RAND()` will perform faster, though.

Comment: Sure, but then again you -can- trigger query caching, limiting the impact.